# plist and Resource folder missing

Tags: plist

I would like to store some basic data of my application in a .plist file; many tutorials suggest to create a new plist file with: ADD -> NEW FILE and store it in Resources folder. I've no Resource file in my application.... where could I store it? Thanks a lot, Giuseppe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can put the file wherever I want in the project! The code will find it with the search pat :)